# Python3 numpy array

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data file containing random values(without equal spacing) ranging between -5.07 to +6.01(390 values in total). I have to seperate these values according to some conditions like;
-5 to -4 as A
-4 to -3 as B etc.,
and finally add how many A/B/C... are present in total.
The codes are given below. On execution they are printing 'A' 390 times as output. Where is the error?

```
file = "86M"
v = np.loadtxt(file, delimiter = "\n")
A = B = C = 0
i = 0
while i < len(v):
  if -5 < v[i] >= -4:
   A = A+1
   print (A)
   i += 1
```

Comment: Change your if line to `if -5 < v[i] and  v[i] >= -4:`

Comment: If `v[i] > -5` and `v[i] >=-4` then simply `v[i] >= -4`, which I don't think you intend (and are not implementing correctly if you do). I think you intend `-5 < v[i] <= -4`

Comment: Thankyou. I found the error and the program is working fine.